# Issue with Ngfor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: arrays, string, ngfor, ionic4

error
supporting object 'Active' of type '`string`'. `NgFor` only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I was trying to make it where every time i click the toggle it will change the `{{ setting }}` from Inactive to active. was trying to get this method working if the other one fails to be possible.

### code html:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Front Door</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="fdoor" ng-model="ni_toggle" (ionChange)="Fdoor()" (click)="change()"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
 <div *ngFor="let setting of sett">
   {{ setting }}
 </div>
```

### ts:

```
active: string = "Active"
inactive: string = "Inactive"


change() {
    if(this.fdoor = true) {
      this.sett = this.active
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your purpose. But I think you should do like this:

```
sett = false;
change() {
    if(this.fdoor = true) {
      this.sett = !this.sett;
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Front Door</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="fdoor" ng-model="ni_toggle" (ionChange)="Fdoor()" (click)="change()"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
 <div>
   {{ sett ? "Active" : "Inactive" }}
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks! and my purpose is basically pressing an on / off switch and the output shows if its on or off.

Comment: Then I think you need to understand `ngFor` and `ngIf` :)